# Python Reading file to dataframe and converting structure

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python Pandas. I have a csv file which is 20 comma separated words wide per line. Each "word" is same length and looks like `0x98, 0x2e, 0x0b`, etc. Words are arranged as:

```
Word1, Word2, Word3 .......Word20 /nl
.
Word21, Word22, Word23...  Word40 /nl
.
Word41, Word42, Word43...  Word60 /nl
.
etc for for 500 lines.
```

Is there an easy way to transpose the horizontal data upon reading the csv into a dataframe so the words are arranged sequentially in a dataframe like this:

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
.
Word21
etc.
```

Comment: You can use the `csv` package to read each row and `extend` a list. Then make a DataFrame from that list.

Comment: Do you mean [pandas.DataFrame.transpose()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)?